# DateTime and Offset Subtlety

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm researching the "mechanics" of `DateTime` and related classes in the `BCL`.
I'm interested in the following odd behavior. Consider the following code snippet:

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2014, 10, 24, 15, 30, 00, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
DateTimeOffset dto2 = new DateTimeOffset(dt1, TimeSpan.FromHours(6));
string input = dto2.ToString("o");
DateTime dt6 = DateTime.Parse(input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
Console.WriteLine("DT6:" + dt6.ToString("o"));
```

I know I should parse the string to the `DateTimeOffset`, but I'm just wondering why the library allows me to do what I do here and the most interesting thing is why the output will be: `"DT6:2014-10-24T13:30:00.00000000+04:00"`
What it did during the parsing is that it set the offset to the actual offset at the given period of time in the time zone of my local machine and adjusted the hours by the delta between the initial offset and the resulting one.
It does this no matter what I provide as the `DateTimeStyles` option. The kind of the resulting value is set to `Local`, also no matter either I provide the `Roundtrip` value or not.
So the question is why it sets the kind to `Local` by default and the second question is where `DateTime` stores the offset and if it stores it, why the hell we need the `DateTimeOffset` class?

Comment: DateTime can only store UTC or local time.  So its Parse() method has to do *something* reasonable if the string specifies a timezone offset.  You are seeing a reasonable choice, you did not specify DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal.  If you need to know the offset then you'll have to use DateTimeOffset.Parse() of course.  At least one reason why the hell you need it.

Comment: @HansPassant I was astonished, that DateTime can store an offset actually. Is it stored as a TimeSpan inside, don't you know? The interesting question then (though I feel like this is a rhetoric question) is why DateTimeOffset was introduced in the case DateTime by itself somehow tries to deal with an offset?

Comment: It does not store an offset.  It uses 2 bits to keep track of the DateTimeKind.  That the Parse() method is smart enough to handle an offset in the string is not relevant to what DateTime can store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` are both structs, not classes.  They are [value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).
- Your question boils down to understanding the behavior of the `DateTime.Parse` method - not the `DateTime` struct.  I suggest reading [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx) for that method.  There are lots of good bits of information there that describe the subtlety of behaviors you are seeing.
- The docs have this to say about the return type [in the "Return value" section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx#Returns) (emphasis mine):

  > Generally, the Parse method returns a DateTime object whose Kind property is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. *However,* the Parse method **may also perform time zone conversion** and set the value of the Kind property differently, depending on the values of the `s` and `styles` parameters:
  >
  > [image: chart]

  You're passing a value of `"2014-10-24T15:30:00.0000000+06:00"` in the `s` parameter, which contains a time zone offset, so you're affected by the first row in the chart, and the result is converted to your machine's local time zone, whatever that may be.
- The `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` flag is not going to have any affect here.  You'd only see the effect if your input ended in a `Z` instead of an offset, such that the third row in the chart above applied.  In that case, the `RoundTripKind` flag ensures `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  Without it you'd still get `DateTimeKind.Local`.
- The offset is not stored.  The only thing *stored* in a `DateTime` is a value combining `Ticks` and `Kind` properties into one [64-bit private field](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,f3e44e197be7d1c9).

  As an interesting side note, recognize that since two bits of this field are reserved for Kind, there are *four* possible states, even though there are only three `DateTimeKind` values exposed.  Indeed, there is a hidden *fourth* kind, which is described under "DateTime's Deep Dark Secret" in [this article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/), and [in the references sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,40).  (Basically, it's a variation on `DateTimeKind.Local`.)
- If you want a date/time API that makes better sense, consider using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org).

Comment: Matt, thank you very much. Matt, I've watched your Pluralsight course and it was very interesting. There is a possibility that I'll have a talk on the DotNext conference in Moscow and hopefully, I'll talk about Date and Time in .NET. That's why I'm trying to gather the most interesting stuff on the topic.

Comment: As to the topic. If the DateTime contains only the two portions of data mentioned above, then where the offset comes from when I call the ToString with the "o" format?

Comment: From your local time zone.  The one set in Windows globally for your computer.

Comment: Oh, so it every time just asks the TimeZoneInfo, seemingly. BTW, I just blurt "classes" , of course, I know these types are structs)))

Comment: Yep.  Essentially, it uses `TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetUtcOffset` (or a shortcutted equivalent, IIRC).  And yeah, I mix up struct/class all the time too. Sometimes I just say "object" so I don't have to think about it too hard.  Especially when talking about other languages that don't necessarily have classes. ;)